# MYSQL server - only update value if not null

Tags: mysql, database, url

I would like to only update a value if it isn't null or an empty string, but i've tried everything from `COALESCE(new_value, old_value)` to `COALESCE(NullIf(RTrim(new_value),'')old_value)`.

I'm completely lost for ideas and I've been browsing the internet for a solution, but I can't find anything that works for me.

```
$query = "UPDATE Person SET fornavn=COALESCE($escapedFornavn,fornavn), efternavn='$escapedEfternavn', alder='$escapedAlder', email='$escapedEmail', adresse='$escapedAdresse', telefon=$escapedTelefon WHERE brugernavn='$brugernavn'; ";
```

I want the query above to only update each value if the user has typed in a value in a form, if the form is empty it should just use the old value.

Comment: You mean use new value only if the **new value** is not empty ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to replace the old value if there is no need.

Comment: You should handle this in application code. if using php, look for `!empty()`

Comment: I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: You should be using placeholder values instead of string interpolation. Escaping is something you can forget and then you've got problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, if you use the mysql `COALESCE` function as assumed. Also `nullif` is required, but you used it wrong.

When you are generating this code with php, you have to consider how String values are handled compared to `null` values (String values need quotes, NULL does not):

```
$query = "UPDATE Person SET fornavn=COALESCE('$escapedFornavn',fornavn)"
```

will work as expected, if `$esapedFornavn` is a valid String. However, if `$esapedFornavn==null` the query will look like the first one, while you want the second one...

```
UPDATE Person SET fornavn=COALESCE('',fornavn);
UPDATE Person SET fornavn=COALESCE(null,fornavn);
```

So, to achieve what is required, you can use `nullif` to turn empty Strings into real `nulls`:

```
UPDATE Person SET fornavn=COALESCE(nullif('$escapedFornavn', ''),fornavn)
```

Basic tests:

```
SELECT COALESCE(nullif(null,''),"oldvalue") -- will return "oldvalue", so no update.
SELECT COALESCE(nullif("newvalue",''),"oldvalue") -- will return "newvalue", so the change is persisted.
```

The only drawback: you cannot set something to empty string, as this will preserve the old value:

```
SELECT COALESCE( NULLIF('',  ''), "oldvalue") --returns oldvalue
```

A Workaround would be to store a single whitespace instead, and use `trim()` whenever you are going to display it:

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but again I keep getting a syntax error. I've tried retyping the entire query but I can't see where I'm doing it wrong.
`$query = "UPDATE Person SET fornavn=COALESCE(nullif($escapedFornavn,''),fornavn), efternavn=COALESCE(nullif($escapedEfternavn,'')efternavn), alder=COALESCE(nullif($escapedAlder,''),alder), email=COALESCE(nullif($escapedEmail,''),email), adresse=COALESCE(nullif($escapedAdresse,''),adresse), telefon=COALESCE(nullif($escapedTelefon,''), telefon) WHERE brugernavn='$brugernavn';";`

Comment: @Andreas2200 You are missing the quotes around string types, for example: `... email=COALESCE(nullif('$escapedEmail',''),email), ...`

Comment: I feel so stupid now, it works. Thank you very much^^

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, handle it in application. I hope this query would be useful somehow.

```
UPDATE Person SET fornavn=IF(fornavn is NULL,NULL,new_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using UPDATE SELECT to get the data into your query, and then using

```
 SET target.column = IF(source.column is invalid, target.column, source.column)
```

When you SET a column to itself, you don't change it.

Here's a possible example.

```
UPDATE p
   SET p.col1 = IF(q.col1 IS NULL OR LENGTH(q.col1) = 0, p.col1, q.col1),
       p.col1 = IF(q.col2 IS NULL OR LENGTH(q.col2) = 0, p.col2, q.col2),
       p.col1 = IF(q.col3 IS NULL OR LENGTH(q.col3) = 0, p.col3, q.col3),
               ...
 FROM Person AS p
 JOIN (
       SELECT 
           <<<value1>> col1,
           <<<value2>> col2,
           <<<value3>> col3,
               ...
      ) AS q
WHERE <<<whatever condition>>>
```